# Change image name before storing

Tags: php

This is my code. I would like to change the file name before storing it in the uploads folder, but can't seem to figure out how. Thanks.

```
// Check for errors
if($_FILES['file_upload']['error'] > 0){
die('An error ocurred when uploading.');
}

if(!getimagesize($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'])){
die('Please ensure you are uploading an image.');
}

// Check filetype
if($_FILES['file_upload']['type'] != 'image/png'){
die('Unsupported filetype uploaded.');
}

// Check filesize
if($_FILES['file_upload']['size'] > 700000){
die('File uploaded exceeds maximum upload size.');
}


// Check if the file exists
if(file_exists('../uploads/profilepics/' . $_FILES['file_upload']['name'])){
die('File with that name already exists.');
}

// Upload file
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], '../uploads/profilepics/' . $_FILES['file_upload']['name'])){
die('Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.');
}

// File uploaded succesfully - upload to server and to DB
die('File uploaded successfully.');
```

Comment: Look up move_uploded_file in the manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a new file name by generating a new unique string and grab extension from file name uploaded, and simply pass it to `move_uploaded_file`

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file_upload']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$nFileName = md5(time()).'.'.$extension;


// Upload file
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], '../uploads/profilepics/' . $nFileName)){
    die('Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked - I need 7 minutes before I can tick your answer as correct :)