# On upload copy image and move to a different folder

Tags: php, image

I am currently using the following to upload an image into a folder but I am finding that for my specific purpose I need to copy the image as it is uploaded and add it to a folder a little higher up in the directory.

Example: The image file gets uploaded to **/folder/folder/images** and this is good. I need it there. However, I also need a copy with the same file with the same filename here: **/folder/images**

Here is the PHP I am using to upload the image to begin with. How can I mdify it to also copy and add to the other folder as a new image is uploaded?

```
<?php
  // A list of permitted file extensions
  $allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip');

  if(isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0){

  $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
  echo '{"status":"error"}';
  exit;
}

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
  'images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'])){
  $tmp='images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
  echo 'images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
  //echo '{"status":"success"}';
  exit;
  }
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
?>
```

**UPDATE**:

Here is the code that got things working for me:

```
<?php
  // A list of permitted file extensions
  $allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip');

  if(isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0){

  $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
  echo '{"status":"error"}';
  exit;
 }

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'])){
   $tmp='images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
   $new = '../images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']; //adapt path to your needs;
   if(copy($tmp,$new)){
     echo 'images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
   //echo '{"status":"success"}';
  }
  exit;
 }
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
?>
```

Comment: why don't you just repeat the `if(move_uploaded_file)` a second time after the first have been executed (using copy() the first time and move the second?)?

Comment: that sounds like it might work, hadn't thought of that ... I'll give it a go

Comment: let me know if you need me to put it as a solution with the entire code..

Comment: that would be helpful ... thanks

Comment: Yeah this is really quite easy to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments on your question:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'])){
    $tmp='images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $new = 'newFolder/'.$_FILES['file']['name']; //adapt path to your needs;
    if(copy($tmp,$new)){
        echo 'images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        //echo '{"status":"success"}';
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: check now. I have updated the $new definition that was missing a /

Comment: not that much... what line it happens? what do you have at that line?

Comment: ok ... in the first line there is a bracket missing in fromt of 'name'] ... I fixed that and it now works ... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) it!

```
$source='folder/folder/images/imageexists.jpg';
$destination='folder/images/imagedoesnotexists.jpg';
if(!copy($source, $destination)){
    //copy failed
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this will work because images are uploaded by users and I would have no way of knowing filenames.

Comment: why not, generate a new filename `md5(time())` concat the extension you get from file uploaded by user using `pathinfo`

Comment: You will overwriting user files, if another user will also upload with same file name, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691825/change-image-name-before-storing/30691867#30691867)

Answer (score 0):

Is good idea to use `copy()` function.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
  'images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'])){
  $tmp='images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
  echo 'images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];

  copy($tmp,'/folder/images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
  //echo '{"status":"success"}';
  exit;
  }
```

Comment: I'll give this a quick try ... I think its what I was after.

Comment: @KulerGary, be sure that '/folder/images/' is right full path. Maybe it's must be 'folder/images/'.

Comment: seems like it should work except that it keeps trowing a 404 error ... makes me think that the path is incorrect

Comment: or perhaps it is trying to copy the image before it uploads